# Add color to text box based on value

Tags: ms-access

The access report has the following script. 
The report has many records (or rows of data) and each one has the text box `CompColor`. 
So, the report colors all the `CompColor` text boxes the same, depending on which one you click in the report.  How can I make each one correct based on teh value entered in that text box?

```
Private Sub Report_Current()
Select Case Me.CompColor
    Case "Green"
        Me.CompColor.BackColor = vbGreen
    Case "Red"
        Me.CompColor.BackColor = vbRed
    Case "Yellow"
        Me.CompColor.BackColor = vbYellow
    Case Else
        Me.CompColor.BackColor = vbWhite
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA010208133.aspx).